# How to send a fcm push notification to a user nodejs?

Tags: node.js, triggers, google-cloud-functions, amazon-sns

I am trying to send a push notification to the users when they checked-in in our app after the 4 hours i want to send a push notification. i have created an endpoint profile where i receive the profile and for example i have checked-in in the app at 10:00 AM then i want to send a push notification at 2:00 PM and 6:00 PM after that i don't want to send any notification in that day.
I am trying to use aws fcm push notification where i have created a topic and in my project i using onWrite trigger also but don't know how to proceed with this problem.

```
const profile = async (req, res) => {
  try {//this is the endpoint where i receive the profile and i wanted to pass a function called 
sendReminder(req.body)

}
catch(error){
console.error(error)}
})
```

and in sendReminder function i want to perform the notification logic but i think it's execute whenever a new profile comes up.so i am really confused from where to start

here is my sendReminer code and currently i am using 59 minutes but i wanted to use 4 hours or 3 hours and it works but i wanted to close the execution after 7:00 Pm

```
const cron = require("node-cron");
const { db } = require("../constant");
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
// const { getAuth } = require('../utils/reportUtils');
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "",
  secretAccessKey: "",
  region: "us-east-1",
});
const sns = new AWS.SNS();

const sendReminder = async (profile) => {
  console.log(profile);
  const updateSnapshot = await db
    .collection("Updates")
    .where("phoneNumber", "==", profile.phoneNumber)
    .get();
  const updateArray = updateSnapshot.docs.map(
    (doc) => doc.data().registrationToken
  );
  console.log("registerToken", updateArray[0]);

  cron.schedule("*/59 * * * *", () => {
    console.log("running a task every 59 minutes");
    let params = {
      PlatformApplicationArn:
        "",
      Token: `${updateArray[0]}`,
    };

    let payload2 = JSON.stringify({
      default: "push notification",
      GCM: JSON.stringify({
        notification: {
          body:
            "Hi ",
          title: "Reminder",
        },
        // data: {
        //   testdata: "Check out these awesome deals!",
        //   url: "www.amazon.com",
        // },
      }),
    });
    sns.createPlatformEndpoint(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        sns.publish(
          {
            Message: payload2, // Required
            MessageStructure: "json",
            TargetArn: data.EndpointArn,
          },
          (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err.stack);
            } else {
              console.log(data);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });
};
module.exports = { sendReminder };
```

Comment: you should post the relevant code as well (except of course critical details like authentication passwords) in order to have a meaningful answer

Comment: @NikosM. basically i am trying a way to implement i have not found any solution that's why i have posted this question

Comment: you should post the code of `sendReminder` as well. In any case you need some secondary storage in order to store the reminder messages and when they should be sent. Then periodicaly the code checks the reminder messages (eg with a cron job) and sends them as push notifications using an aproopriate api (you can look them up)

Comment: @NikosM. can you please suggest how can i stop this after 7 pm?

Comment: My suggestion (although there can be other approaches) is to store in secondary storage (eg DB) the messages, the time to be sent and to whom (and any other relevant info). There is a single running cron job in a small interval (eg every 5 minutes). The cron-job checks the storage for messages which should be sent around that time and sents them and deletes them (or marks them as sent whatever). Then when you engage another user, code simply updates the storage with the messages to be sent and at what time and the continously running cron-job takes care to sent them at the right time.